# issue with showing text in entry box in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been playing around in Tkinter trying to build up my skills and I keep running into this problem with the entry box

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root=Tk()
NAME = StringVar()
NAME.set("724-###-###")
def EDIT(*args):
    #Create Toplevel#
    TP_E = Toplevel(root)
    TP_E.title=("Edit:")
    TP_E.geometry("+575+375")
    TP_E.focus()

    name = NAME.get()
    print(name)
    ttk.Entry(TP_E, textvariable=name).grid(column=1, row=1)

EDIT()


root.mainloop()
```

I was having EDIT() run as the command with a button, but I pulled this out to test it. My question is. Why isn't the phone number showing up in the entry box. The variable "name" gets the number so why isn't it showing up as text already in the entry box. I have gotten it to work before in other scripts so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `textvariable` attribute must be one of the special tkinter variables (`StringVar`, etc.).

Change your code to this:

ttk.Entry(TP_E, textvariable=NAME).grid(column=1, row=1)

Comment: I wasn't originally going to use that variable because it we outside of the function, but I think that it will actually work out better like that in the context of the whole script. Thanks for your help. I thought that since NAME was a StringVar than name would be as well. Since I used the get() method. Thanks again.